# Regex string contain just digits and *,#,+ in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to implement a function in Javascript that verify a string.
The pattern i must to do is contain only digits charactor, *, # and +.
For example:

```
+182031203
+12312312312*#
+2131*1231#
*12312+#
#123*########
```

I tried alot of thing like

```js
/^[\d]{1,}[*,#,+]{1,}$
```

but it's doesn't work. I am not sure that i understand good in regex. Please help.

Comment: You could attempt to match `[^\d*#+]` and negate the results; that is, the string contains only the permissible characters if and only if this match fails (assuming the string is not empty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the pattern `^[0-9*#+]+$`:

```js
var inputs = ["+182031203", "+12312312312*#", "+2131*1231#", "12312+#", "#123########"];
for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    console.log(inputs[i] + " => " + /^[0-9*#+]+$/.test(inputs[i]));
}
```

Comment: `^[0-9*#+]*$` if a string could be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)

```
/^[0-9\*\#\+]+$/g
```

0-9 matches a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
* matches the character * with index 4210 (2A16 or 528) literally (case sensitive)
# matches the character # with index 3510 (2316 or 438) literally (case sensitive)
+ matches the character + with index 4310 (2B16 or 538) literally (case sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```js
const rxDigitsAndSomeOtherCharacters = /^(\d+|[*#]+)+$/;
```

Breaking it down:

- `^` start-of-text, followed by
- `(` a [capturing] group, consisting of

  - `\d+` one or more digits
  - `|` or...
  - `[*#+]+` one ore more of `*`, `#` or `+`
- `)+`, the [capturing] group being repeated 1 or more times, and followed by
- `$` end-of-text